# Unable to fix security vulnerabilities in Sharepoint Application

Tags: sharepoint

I have made a Sharepoint application in my organization and raised a request for security assessment. The security team has given the following vulnerabilities:

1. Unencrypted Web Config file

   Is is possible to encrypt? I am facing application error while encrypting the config file.
2. Server Version Disclosure (HTTPAPI/2.0)

   Security team suggested to add `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");` to add in `Global.ascx` file. Where is this file? I don't have any such file.
3. Cookie with Insecure or Improper or Missing SameSite attribute

   How can I fix this issue in Sharepoint? Our org uses Microsoft SSO for auth.
4. Content-Security-Policy with 'unsafe-inline -

   How can I fix this in Sharepoint application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to encrypt the web.config file in SharePoint. You can use the command "aspnet_regiis.exe -pef" to encrypt the web.config file. If you are facing application errors while encrypting the config file, you can try to troubleshoot the errors or seek help from a SharePoint expert.

To remove the Server Version Disclosure header, you can add the following code to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="Server" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

If you don't have a Global.ascx file, you can create one in the App_Code folder of your SharePoint application.

To fix the Cookie with Insecure or Improper or Missing SameSite attribute issue, you can add the SameSite attribute to the cookie in the web.config file. Here is an example:

```
<system.web>
  <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

To fix the Content-Security-Policy with 'unsafe-inline issue, you can add the following meta tag to the master page of your SharePoint application:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
```

Please note that these fixes may not be exhaustive and you may need to consult with a SharePoint expert for a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Small update... Connected with Microsoft for encrypting web config file. They generally don't recommend encrypting it for Sharepoint 2016/2019 since sometimes changes in the web config would be overwritten automatically by the Sharepoint application. However, Sharepoint Subscription Edition automatically encrypts the sensitive sections of the web config file.